# How to return value from function? (translate actionscript to c#)

Tags: c#, .net, return

So... I want to return value when C# function is called. I need a code example (simple summ of a,b values will be ok) Please help

I need something like this ( I know ActionScript so I will write in it):

```
public function sum(valueA:int, valueB:int):int 
{
   var summ:int = valueA + valueB;
   return summ;
}
```

How to translate it into C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side-note, C# (3.0 above) also supports the `var` keyword when declaring variables, which means that you can write:

```
public int Sum(int valueA, int valueB) { 
  var summ = valueA + valueB; 
  return summ; 
}
```

The meaning of `var` is porbably different than in ActionScript - it looks at the expression used to initialize the variable and uses the type of the expression (so the code is statically-typed). In the example above, the type of `summ` will be `int` just like in the version posted by Oded.

(This is often a confusing thing for people with background in dynamic languages, so I thought it would be useful to mention this, especially since `var` is also a keyword in ActionScript).

Comment: and if I need to concat 2 strings vill 'var' work? like ' var summ = valueA + " "+ valueB; '

Comment: Yes, it will work. The compiler knows that `valueA` and `valueB` are both `int` and so it will figure out that you're adding two integers, so the result will also be integer (and therefore it will infer that `summ` is integer)

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
public int sum(int valueA, int valueB)
{
    int summ = valueA + valueB;
    return summ;
}
```

Differences to note:

- The return type is declared immediately after the `public` visiblity qualifier
- Variable types are declared before them

Answer (score 0):

Or even so =)

```
public int Sum ( int valueA, int valueB ) { return valueA + valueB; }
```

if you don't need to store a result in a function for some purpose.